# CFQ vs Deadline - performance benefits

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, performance-tuning

Running CPanel and wondering what would be the best for web hosting?

deadline is more balanced over CFQ right so would allow for more I/O activities right

Comment: No, you're running linux. Sorry for the snark, but too many people seem to think that cPanel is the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The [CFQ algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ) is intended for process and resource sharing. It is also compatible with [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice). The [deadline scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadline_scheduler) is geared towards providing priority to intensive processes.

This is easy for you to test. Try it in your environment both ways and see how it goes.